# Linker issue calling the D3DX10CreateEffectFromFile() method

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++, directx

Having issues trying to retrieve a effect file for directX. If I do not include the  D3DX10CreateEffectFromFile() method, the application compiles correctly. If I do include it. I get the following error

```
1>GXDX.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3DX10CreateEffectFromFileW@48 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall GXDX::StartUp(struct HWND__ * *,int,int)" (?StartUp@GXDX@@UAEXPAPAUHWND__@@HH@Z)
1>C:\Users\numerical25\Desktop\Intro ToDirectX\GODFILES\GXRenderManager\GXRenderManager\Debug\GXRenderManager.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

My first thought was maybe it is not linking the directx library correctly. But I find that to be off cause I am including the lib files and I am using other methods with no problem. below is my code.

### header file

```
#ifndef GXDX_
#define GXDX_

#include "GXRenderer.h"
#include <d3d10.h>
#include <d3dx10.h>
#include "GXExceptions.h"


#pragma comment (lib, "d3d10.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx10.lib")

class GXDX: public GXRenderer {
protected:
    ID3D10Device* gm_dxDevice;
    IDXGISwapChain* gm_swapChain;
    ID3D10RenderTargetView* gm_renderTargetView;
    ID3D10Effect *gm_shader;
    ID3D10EffectTechnique *gm_tech;
public:
    void CleanUp();
    void StartUp(HWND* window,int w, int h);
    void SetupScene();
    void DisplayScene();
    void LoadMesh(GXVector*,UINT*);
    void DrawText(LPSTR);
};

#endif
```

below is the implementation

```
void GXDX::StartUp(HWND* mainWindow,int w, int h)
{
    width = w;
    height = h;
    this->m_mainWindow = mainWindow;

    //Get size of window
    RECT rectangle;
    GetClientRect(*m_mainWindow,&rectangle);

    ID3D10Texture2D *backBufferSurface;

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc;
    
    SecureZeroMemory(&swapChainDesc, sizeof(swapChainDesc));

    swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 2;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = width;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = height;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = *mainWindow;
    swapChainDesc.Windowed = TRUE;
    swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT; 

    D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE driverType = D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE;

    HRESULT hr = D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,driverType,NULL,0,
        D3D10_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc,&gm_swapChain,&gm_dxDevice);

    if(FAILED(hr))
        throw GXVideoException(L"Problems retrieving directX device");

    hr = gm_swapChain->GetBuffer(0,__uuidof(ID3D10Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&backBufferSurface);

    if(FAILED(hr))
        throw GXVideoException(L"Failure to retrieve buffer from swap chain");

    hr = gm_dxDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(backBufferSurface, NULL,&gm_renderTargetView); 
    backBufferSurface->Release();

    if(FAILED(hr))
        throw GXVideoException(L"Failure to create Render Target View");
    

    //In the future, you might want to change this to something that allows multiple views
    //Like for an editor
    gm_dxDevice->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &gm_renderTargetView, NULL);

    UINT rectangle_width = rectangle.right - rectangle.left;
    UINT rectangle_height = rectangle.bottom - rectangle.top;

    D3D10_VIEWPORT viewport;

    viewport.TopLeftX = 0; 
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
    viewport.Width = rectangle_width;
    viewport.Height = rectangle_height;
    viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;

    //bind viewport
    gm_dxDevice->RSSetViewports(1,&viewport);

    D3D10_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] = 
    {
        {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA},
    };
    

    hr = D3DX10CreateEffectFromFile(L"shader.fx", NULL, NULL,
        "fx_4_0",D3D10_SHADER_DEBUG,0,gm_dxDevice,NULL,NULL, &gm_shader,NULL,NULL);// Error here and dont know why

}
```

Comment: Did you include d3dx10.lib in Tools\Options\Project and Solutions\VC++\Directories\Library files?

Comment: I shouldnt have to if I got pragma comments. I thought there was 2 ways to do it. Include it in the solution options, or use pragma comments

Comment: I think your pragma comment can either have the full path or be based on the paths you've set up. Since you're just saying the file names, check your paths.

Answer (score 0):

Gotta love linker errors.  I mostly use DX9 at the moment, but I recall DX11 ditching effects (but still having them available).  However, DX10 should still have them.  Peeking through d3dx10async.h showed that the CompileEffectFromFile is still in there (June 2010 sdk), however.  I noticed that the D3DX10CompileEffectFromFile is listed as deprecated in MSDN, with [D3DX10CompileFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310586(v=VS.85).aspx) being its replacement.  Double check your library links and try giving the D3DX10CompileFromFile function a shot (although theoretically if the CompileEffect func is still fully there and libraries are linked correctly it *should* work).

Comment: I am not using D3DX10CompileEffectFromFile . I am using D3DX10CreateEffectFromFile . As for DX11 ditching effects. I think that is ridiculous. If they are going to keep jumping around like that. Then I think they need to slow down with the updates, and do better critical  thinking.

Comment: Also, the intellisense picks up the CreateEffectFromFile, but not a CompileEffectFromFile

Comment: Ah, my mistake about the "Compile" and "Create", sorry.  I agree it gets kind of confusing with the constant changes for people who don't stay up to date all the time.  I believe the thinking was devs could study the code (and compile and use it if they want) and create their own effect frameworks (which happens anyway), but it's still kind of a pain.  Anyway, glad you sorted your problem out.

Comment: DX11 doesn't ditch effects.  Instead they give you the full source code to the effect system and let you do what the f**k you like with it :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue was that I didnt have the lib paths supplied in the additional lib directories under general in the solutions options area. I should of known that but it threw me off because any other method I called before this issue, worked fine.